# Open different graphical image files and draw them on the background of the main application window, using GDI+ library

Tags: c++, winapi, gdi+

I met some problems while using GDI+ for drawing different images in my program.

My program represents a window with a button and a background.

Logic of my program intended to work in the following way:

- When user hits the button, an open file dialog box must open and ask
  user to select an image file.
- When user is done with that, program must draw that file on the background of the   main   (and single) program window.

My problem is that all Gdiplus objects doesn't have a default constructors.

So even when I choose FromFile method, my bitmap object still have the same picture, assigned in constructor, so I didn't even realize how to change them dynamically.

Can you advice some solution to that problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Image::FromFile() method is **static**, it returns a newly constructed Image object that contains the image.  Think of it as a factory method.  Without seeing code, I'd have to guess that you forgot to use the return value of the method.